# non-static data member initializers c++

Tags: c++, c++11, non-static, data-members

```
non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 
[enabled by default]
     int Red = 255;
non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
[enabled by default]
     int Green = 255;
non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 
[enabled by default]
     int Blue = 255;
```

Not sure why this doesn't work.

```
struct color {
    int Red = 255;
    int Green = 255;
    int Blue = 255;
};
```

Comment: I think you should follow your compiler's advice.

Comment: When you get answers, you're supposed to pick the one that answered your question, and you click the checkmark. I see you have not done this for any of the questions you have asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable c++11 or:

```
struct Color
{
    int Red;
    int Green;
    int Blue;
    Color() : Red(255), Green(255), Blue(255) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Non-static data member initializers is a feature that exists only to C++11 version of language specification. The compiler you are using does not work in C++11 mode by default. In order to switch your compiler to C++11 mode you have to specify the `-std=c++11` (or `-std=gnu++11`) command-line option. This is what your compiler is telling you (quite unambiguously, I might add).

There's no such feature in pre-C++11 versions of the language. That's why it "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable C++ 11 or add the `-std=c++11` flag to compile because what you are trying to do is only available in C++11

Answer (score 0):

Pre-C++11, you could only initialize non-static data members in the member initializer list of the constructor. In C++11, you can use brace-or-equal initializers as shown in your code. However, if your NSDM has a brace-or-equal initializer and appears in the member initializer list, the brace-or-equal initializer is ignored. Therefore, the following will work for both C++03 and C++11:

```
struct Color
{
    int Red;
    int Green;
    int Blue;
    Color() : Red(255), Green(255), Blue(255) {}
};
```

However, since you have a C++11 ready compiler, use `-std=c++11` to enable it.